How to 'take' batches of a KQL query using a batch file?
I want to take the lines of text resulting from a KQL query in batches of 50, (50/50/../remainder). How can I do that using a batch file?
I can use take 50 to take the first 50 rows, but how to take the 51th-100th and the 101th to last rows?

You could do the following:
let Events = datatable(EventId:int)
[
    101,
    102,
    103,
    104,
    105,
    106,
    107,
    108,
    109,
    110,
    111,
    112,
    113,
    114,
    115,
    116,
    117,
    118,
    119,
    120,
    121,
    122,
    123,
    124,
    125,
    126,
    127,
    128,
    129,
    130
];
let batchSize = 5;
let numberedEvents = Events
| serialize rn = row_number();
let eventsWithBatch = numberedEvents
| extend batchNumber = floor((rn - 1) / batchSize, 1);
eventsWithBatch
| summarize EventIdsList = make_list(EventId) by batchNumber

Here the Sample Code to test.

But this is not a real loop or a real pagination, you maybe want to have for your unions from your other question :). Thats not possible for unions.

if you must use pagination (e.g., cause your client has such small capacity that can't even hold a several thousands of records in memory), you can use 'stored query results'. see example here
that said, you may find it much more efficient to simply fetch the entire result set from the service once, and have the client application deal with presenting 'pages'.
